# Greek characters- jsp

Tags: jsp

i need your help! I have a project and i face a problem with greek characters. It shows me ?????? when i pass a parameter.
Here is my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page import="myimpact_package.DonatorDAO" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*,java.lang.*"%>





<% 
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getCharacterEncoding();
 response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

 %>



<%-- Take organization's name --%>



<%
String info=""; 
 if ((request.getParameter("info")!=null)){ 
 info=request.getParameter("info"); 
 info= new String(info.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");  
 }

 %>



 <%-- First choice : Login.jsp calls ConfirmationController --%>



<% String code=request.getParameter("code"); 
int id=Integer.parseInt(code);
if (id==1) {
   String username =request.getParameter("username");
   String password =request.getParameter("password"); 

    DonatorDAO dondao = new DonatorDAO();
    dondao.open(); 

  if ((dondao.isUserValid(username,password))==true) { 
  session.setAttribute("login","0d1b450a-e7ff-422c-9fc8-77195ae57a9f");
  request.setAttribute("username",username);
  request.setAttribute("password",password);
  session.setAttribute("username",username);
  session.setAttribute("password",password);
  dondao.close(); 


  %>


 <%
  if((session.getAttribute("checkpaymentform")!=null)&&(request.getParameter("info")!=null)){
     session.removeAttribute("checkpaymentform");

      RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("paymentform.jsp?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&info="+info);
      rd.forward(request, response);

 }else if((session.getAttribute("checksocialoffer")!=null)&&(request.getParameter("info")!=null)){

     session.removeAttribute("checksocialoffer");
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("socialoffer.jsp?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&info="+info);
     rd.forward(request, response);


 }
 %>
```

Here is socialoffer.jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.lang.*,javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*"%>




<%  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getCharacterEncoding();
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
%>



 <%-- Take organization's name --%>


 <% String info="";

 if ((request.getParameter("info")!=null)){ 

     info=request.getParameter("info"); 
     info= new String(info.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

 }

 %> 



 <% boolean name=false;
    boolean lastname=false;
    boolean offertype=false;
    boolean deliverychoice=false;
    boolean success_message=false;
    name=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("name_access"));
    lastname=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("lastname_access"));
 offertype=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("offer_type_message"));
   deliverychoice=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("donation_delivery_message"));       success_message=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("success_message"));
   %>




 <%-- Don't print error or success message when SocialOfferForm is called  for the first time  --%>




<%

  if ( (request.getParameter("name_access")==null) ||  (request.getParameter("lastname_access")==null) || (request.getParameter("offer_type_message")==null) || (request.getParameter("donation_delivery_message")==null)){
    name=true;
    lastname=true;
    offertype=true;
    deliverychoice=true;
    success_message=false;
  } else {

     if (request.getParameter("name_access")!=null) {
      name=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("name_access"));
  }

  if (request.getParameter("lastname_access")!=null) {
    lastname=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("lastname_access"));
  }

  if (request.getParameter("offer_type_message")!=null) {
      offertype=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("offer_type_message"));
  }

  if (request.getParameter("donation_delivery_message")!=null) {
      deliverychoice=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("donation_delivery_message"));
  }

        success_message=Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("success_message"));
   info=request.getParameter("organization"); 
   info= new String(info.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
 }
 %>   




<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Myimp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div>
        <a href="index.jsp" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="">   </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.jsp">x</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="whydonate.jsp">u</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="allorganizations.jsp">ol</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.jsp">y</a>
          </li>
           <%
           if ((session.getAttribute("username")!=null)&&(session.getAttribute("password")!=null)){ 
            if((!session.getAttribute("username").equals("null"))&&(!session.getAttribute("password").equals("null"))){
            %>
             <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="profile.jsp">kol:<%=session.getAttribute("username")%></a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="logout.jsp"><span>ki</span></a></li>

                 </ul>
            </li>
            <%
            }else{
            %>
            <li>
                <a href="login.jsp">ji</a>
            </li>
            <%
            }}else{
            %>
            <li>
                <a href="login.jsp">ki</a>
            </li>
            <%
            }
            %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">

<div class="content">
    <div class="head">
       <h1>Myimp</h1>
       </div>
       <br> </br>
      <form action="DonationController.jsp?info=<%=info%>&code=1" method="post" class="socialoffer">


      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">ΞΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞ±:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
      <br></br>
     <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ ΟΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
            </div>



            <%-- Wrong name message --%>


            <% if (!name) {

            %>

            <p style="color:#CC0000">Ξ£Ο…ΞΌΟ€Ξ»Ξ·ΟΟΟƒΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ Ο€ΞµΞ΄Ξ―ΞΏ ΞΌΞµ Ο„ΞΏ ΟΞ½ΞΏΞΌΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚.</p>
            <br></br>

            <%
            } 
            %>




           <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="surname">Ξ•Ο€ΟΞ½Ο…ΞΌΞΏ:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ ΞµΟ€Ξ―ΞΈΞµΟ„Ο ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
            </div>




            <%-- Wrong lastname message --%>


            <% if (!lastname) {

            %>

            <p style="color:#CC0000">Ξ£Ο…ΞΌΟ€Ξ»Ξ·ΟΟΟƒΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ Ο€ΞµΞ΄Ξ―ΞΏ ΞΌΞµ Ο„ΞΏ ΞµΟ€ΟΞ½Ο…ΞΌΟ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚.</p>
            <br></br>

            <%
            } 
            %>




         <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="age">Ξ—Ξ»ΞΉΞΊΞ―Ξ±:<span class="asterisc">*     </span></label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" pattern="\d\d" title="##"   required="required" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„Ξ·Ξ½ Ξ·Ξ»ΞΉΞΊΞ―Ξ± ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
                   </div>





             <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="city">Ξ ΟΞ»Ξ·:<span class="asterisc">*</span>  </label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„Ξ·Ξ½ Ο€ΟΞ»Ξ· ΞΊΞ±Ο„ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞ―Ξ±Ο‚ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
            </div>





             <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="address">Ξ”ΞΉΞµΟΞΈΟ…Ξ½ΟƒΞ·:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„Ξ·Ξ½ Ξ΄ΞΉΞµΟΞΈΟ…Ξ½ΟƒΞ· ΞΊΞ±Ο„ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞ―Ξ±Ο‚ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
                   </div>






            <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="telephone">ΞΞΉΞ½Ξ·Ο„Ο Ξ¤Ξ·Ξ»Ξ­Ο†Ο‰Ξ½ΞΏ:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="text" pattern="\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d" title="##########" required="required" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ Ξ±ΟΞΉΞΈΞΌΟ Ο„ΞΏΟ… Ο„Ξ·Ξ»ΞµΟ†ΟΞ½ΞΏΟ… ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
            </div>





            <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="email">Email:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                   <br></br>
                   <input size="112" height="250px" type="email" required="required" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ξ•ΞΉΟƒΞ¬Ξ³ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ email ΟƒΞ±Ο‚">
                   <br></br>
            </div>





      <p>ΞΞ­ΟƒΟ‰ Ξ±Ο…Ο„Ξ®Ο‚ Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο†ΟΟΞΌΞ±Ο‚ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚ Ξ΄Ξ―Ξ½ΞµΟ„Ξµ Ξ· Ξ΄Ο…Ξ½Ξ±Ο„ΟΟ„Ξ·Ο„Ξ± Ξ½Ξ± Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†Ξ­ΟΞµΟ„Ξµ ΟΞΏΟΟ‡Ξ±, Ο„ΟΟΟ†ΞΉΞΌΞ± ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ Ο†Ξ¬ΟΞΌΞ±ΞΊΞ± ΟƒΞµ Ξ±Ξ½ΞΈΟΟΟ€ΞΏΟ…Ο‚, Ξ±Ξ»Ξ»Ξ¬ ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ ΟƒΞµ ΞΏΞΉΞΊΞΏΞ³Ξ­Ξ½ΞµΞΉΞµΟ‚ Ο€ΞΏΟ… Ξ­Ο‡ΞΏΟ…Ξ½ Ξ±Ξ½Ξ¬Ξ³ΞΊΞ· Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ο„Ξ· Ξ²ΞΏΞ®ΞΈΞµΞΉΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚.</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="choose">Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞ»Ξ­ΞΎΟ„Ξµ Ο„Ξ·Ξ½ ΞΊΞ±Ο„Ξ·Ξ³ΞΏΟΞ―Ξ± Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                   <br> </br>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Ξ΅ΞΏΟΟ‡Ξ±">Ξ΅ΞΏΟΟ‡Ξ±</input>
                   <br> </br>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Ξ¤ΟΟΟ†ΞΉΞΌΞ±">Ξ¤ΟΟΟ†ΞΉΞΌΞ±</input>
                   <br> </br>
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Ξ¦Ξ¬ΟΞΌΞ±ΞΊΞ±">Ξ¦Ξ¬ΟΞΌΞ±ΞΊΞ±</input>
                   <br> </br>
                </div>


            <%-- Wrong offertype message --%>


            <% if (!offertype) {

            %>

            <p style="color:#CC0000">Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞ»Ξ­ΞΎΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏ ΞµΞ―Ξ΄ΞΏΟ‚ Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬Ο‚ Ο€ΞΏΟ… ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΞµΞ―Ο„Ξµ.</p>

            <%
            } 
            %>





             <div class="form-group">
                <br> </br>
                <label for="elaborate">Ξ ΞµΟΞΉΞ³ΟΞ¬ΟΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΉ Ξ±ΞΊΟΞΉΞ²ΟΟ‚ ΞΈΞ± Ο€ΞµΟΞΉΞ»Ξ±ΞΌΞ²Ξ¬Ξ½ΞµΞΉ Ξ· Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚(Ο€.Ο‡ Ο€ΞµΟΞΉΞ³ΟΞ¬ΟΟ„Ξµ Ο€ΟΟƒΞ· Ο€ΞΏΟƒΟΟ„Ξ·Ο„Ξ± ΞΈΞ± Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†Ξ­ΟΞµΟ„Ξµ):<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
                <br> </br>
                <textarea name="mytext" required="required" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                <br> </br>
             </div>




             <div class="form-group">
               <br> </br>
               <label>Ξ ΟΟ‚ ΞΈΞ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΞΏΟΟƒΞ±Ο„Ξµ Ξ½Ξ± Ξ΄ΟΟƒΞµΟ„Ξµ Ο„Ξ·Ξ½ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚:<span class="asterisc">*</span></label>
               <br> </br>
               <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΟ Ξ½Ξ± ΟƒΟ„ΞµΞ―Ξ»Ο‰ Ο„Ξ· Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΞΌΞΏΟ… Ο„Ξ±Ο‡Ο…Ξ΄ΟΞΏΞΌΞΉΞΊΟΟ‚">Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΟ Ξ½Ξ± ΟƒΟ„ΞµΞ―Ξ»Ο‰ Ο„Ξ· Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΞΌΞΏΟ… Ο„Ξ±Ο‡Ο…Ξ΄ΟΞΏΞΌΞΉΞΊΟΟ‚
               <br> </br>
               <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΟ Ξ½Ξ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΟƒΞΊΞµΟ†Ο„Ο Ξ±Ο…Ο„ΞΏΟ€ΟΞΏΟƒΟΟ€Ο‰Ο‚ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ ΞΏΟΞ³Ξ±Ξ½ΞΉΟƒΞΌΟ Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ± Ο€Ξ±ΟΞ±Ξ΄ΟΟƒΟ‰ Ο„Ξ· Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΞΌΞΏΟ…">Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΟ Ξ½Ξ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΟƒΞΊΞµΟ†Ο„Ο Ξ±Ο…Ο„ΞΏΟ€ΟΞΏΟƒΟΟ€Ο‰Ο‚ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ ΞΏΟΞ³Ξ±Ξ½ΞΉΟƒΞΌΟ Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ± Ο€Ξ±ΟΞ±Ξ΄ΟΟƒΟ‰ Ο„Ξ· Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΞΌΞΏΟ…
               <br> </br>
               <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="ΞΞ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΞΏΟΟƒΞ± Ξ½Ξ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΊΞΏΞΉΞ½Ο‰Ξ½Ξ®ΟƒΞµΞΉ ΞΊΞ¬Ο€ΞΏΞΉΞΏΟ‚ ΞΌΞ±Ξ¶Ξ― ΞΌΞΏΟ… Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ± ΟƒΟ…Ξ¶Ξ·Ο„Ξ®ΟƒΞΏΟ…ΞΌΞµ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ Ο„ΟΟΟ€ΞΏ Ξ±Ο€ΞΏΟƒΟ„ΞΏΞ»Ξ®Ο‚ Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬Ο‚ ΞΌΞΏΟ…">ΞΞ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΈΟ…ΞΌΞΏΟΟƒΞ± Ξ½Ξ± ΞµΟ€ΞΉΞΊΞΏΞΉΞ½Ο‰Ξ½Ξ®ΟƒΞµΞΉ ΞΊΞ¬Ο€ΞΏΞΉΞΏΟ‚ ΞΌΞ±Ξ¶Ξ― ΞΌΞΏΟ… Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ± ΟƒΟ…Ξ¶Ξ·Ο„Ξ®ΟƒΞΏΟ…ΞΌΞµ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ Ο„ΟΟΟ€ΞΏ Ξ±Ο€ΞΏΟƒΟ„ΞΏΞ»Ξ®Ο‚ Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬Ο‚ ΞΌΞΏΟ…
               <br> </br>




            <%-- Wrong deliverychoice message --%>


            <% if (!deliverychoice) {

            %>

            <p style="color:#CC0000">Ξ•Ο€ΞΉΞ»Ξ­ΞΎΟ„Ξµ Ο„ΞΏΞ½ Ο„ΟΟΟ€ΞΏ Ο€Ξ±ΟΞ¬Ξ΄ΞΏΟƒΞ·Ο‚ Ο„Ξ·Ο‚ Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬Ο‚ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚.</p>

            <%
            } 
            %>


               <div class="col-sm-100">
                  <br> </br>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ξ¥Ο€ΞΏΞ²ΞΏΞ»Ξ®</button>
                  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">AΞΊΟΟΟ‰ΟƒΞ·</button>
               </div>
             </div>





            <%--Success message --%>


            <% if (success_message) { %>

            <br> </br>
            <p style="color:#009900">Ξ— Ο€ΟΞΏΟƒΟ†ΞΏΟΞ¬ ΟƒΞ±Ο‚ ΞΊΞ±Ο„Ξ±Ο‡Ο‰ΟΞ®ΞΈΞ·ΞΊΞµ ΞµΟ€ΞΉΟ„Ο…Ο‡ΟΟ‚.</p>

            <% } %>  
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>

 </body>
```

And here is DonationController.jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page import="myimpact_package.DonationDAO" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*,java.lang.*"%>




<%  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getCharacterEncoding();
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    %>



 <% 
   String code=request.getParameter("code");
   int id=Integer.parseInt(code);
 %>



  <%-- First choice_access : SocialOffer.jsp calls DonationController --%>




   <%
    if (id==1) {

    String organization=""; 
    if ((request.getParameter("info")!=null)){ 
     organization=request.getParameter("info"); 
     organization= new String(organization.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");  
    }

   String firstname=request.getParameter("name");
   String lastname=request.getParameter("surname");
   String age=request.getParameter("age");
   String city=request.getParameter("city");
   String address=request.getParameter("address");
   String telephone_number=request.getParameter("telephone");
   String email_address=request.getParameter("email");
   String kindoffer=request.getParameter("radio1");
   String donation_details=request.getParameter("mytext");
   String donation_delivery_choice_access1=request.getParameter("radio2");


   String offer_type="";
   String donation_delivery_choice_access="";
   String name_access="true";
   String lastname_access="true";
   String offer_type_message="true";
   String donation_delivery_message="true";

   DonationDAO donation = new DonationDAO();
   donation.open();
   boolean a=donation.check_name(firstname);
   boolean b=donation.check_lastname(lastname);
   donation.close();

   if (kindoffer!=null) {
     offer_type=request.getParameter("radio1");
   }

  if  (donation_delivery_choice_access1!=null) {
   donation_delivery_choice_access=request.getParameter("radio2");
  }


 if ((offer_type==null) || (offer_type.equals("")) || (donation_delivery_choice_access==null) || (donation_delivery_choice_access.equals("")) || (a==false) || (b==false)) {

  if ((offer_type==null) || (offer_type.equals(""))) {
     offer_type_message="false";
  }

   if ((donation_delivery_choice_access==null) || (donation_delivery_choice_access.equals(""))){
     donation_delivery_message="false";
   }

   if (a==false) {
     name_access="false";
   }

   if (b==false) {
     lastname_access="false";      
   }

   if ((organization!=null)){ 
    organization=request.getParameter("info"); 
    organization= new String(organization.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");  
   }


   response.sendRedirect("socialoffer.jsp?organization="+organization+"&offer_type_message="+offer_type_message + "&donation_delivery_message=" + donation_delivery_message + "&name_access=" + name_access + "&lastname_access=" + lastname_access);
  }

 else if ((offer_type!=null) || (donation_delivery_choice_access!=null) || (a==true) || (b==true)) {

   if (offer_type!=null) {
      offer_type_message="true";
   }

   if (donation_delivery_choice_access!=null) {
      donation_delivery_message="true";
   }

   if (a==true) {
     name_access="true";
   }

   if (b==true) {
     lastname_access="true";       
   }

   if ((organization!=null)){ 
    organization=request.getParameter("info"); 
    organization= new String(organization.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

}

```
 String success_message="true";
 DonationDAO donation2 = new DonationDAO();
 donation2.open();
    donation2.sendDonation(firstname,lastname,age,city,address,telephone_number,email_address,organization,offer_type,donation_details,donation_delivery_choice_access);
 donation2.close();
 response.sendRedirect("socialoffer.jsp?organization="+organization+"&offer_type_message="+offer_type_message + "&donation_delivery_message=" + donation_delivery_message + "&name_access=" + name_access + "&lastname_access=" + lastname_access + "&success_message=" + success_message);
}
}
%>
```

And the problem is: when from ConfirmationController.jsp the info parameter passes with RequestDispatche to socialoffer.jsp, and then info parameter passes with "action form" to DonationController.jsp and then back to socialoffer with sendRedirect, in url i have this output: socialoffer.jsp?organization=?????&offer_type_message=true&donation_delivery_message=true&name_access=true&lastname_access=true&success_message=true
I tried UTF-without BOM but nothing!

Comment: Try to pass [encoded characters](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html) when you submit the form.

Comment: yes i thought to do this but how i will?

Comment: also, i think that the problem is in ConfirmationController.jsp because if i delete thiw code" response.sendRedirect("socialoffer.jsp?organization="+organization+"&offer_type_message="+offer_type_message + "&donation_delivery_message=" + donation_delivery_message + "&name_access=" + name_access + "&lastname_access=" + lastname_access);
 " from DonationController.jsp in url the output is again info=????